# Access to the variable between multiple scripts for loose coupling in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

For instance, assume we have a health variable in one script and want to access to this variable in UI script for showing health and on the other hand change pitch of sound according to amount of health.
I know some ways to access this variable but they highly dependent scripts to each other. Like GetComponent, Singelton or even C# event.
I want to know is there any patterns to decrease these dependencies ? (Also efficient and performant)

Edit:
This event system is in my mind but I think It has some dependencies which they can be removed but I don't know how and also I'm not sure about it and its performance.

```
public class Player {
    public class HealthEventArgs : EventArgs {
        public int currentHealth;
        public HealthChangedEventArgs(int currentHealth) {
            this.currentHealth = currentHealth;
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler<HealthEventArgs> HealthEvent;

    public void NotifyHealthChanged(int health) {
        if(HealthEvent != null) {
            HealthEvent.Invoke(this, new HealthEventArgs(health));
        }
    }
}

public class OtherClass {
    public void SubscribeToPlayerHealthEvent() {
        Player.HealthEvent += Foo;
    }

    public void UnsubscribeFromPlayerHealthEvent() {
        Player.HealthEvent -= Foo;
    }

    public void Foo(object o, HealthEventArgs e) {
        //Do something with e.currentHealth
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you've mentioned the observer-pattern, events.

Comment: I added more details to my question and removed those tags.

Comment: You should use events... But is it really worth it on a Unity project where all the other components will be tightly coupled by design? I think the Singleton approach is the winner for this kind of projects. You might also want to look into the open source Godot engine. I think their design philosophy is cleaner because instead of Prefabs, every object can be a scene and inherit from another scene (or added as a child).

Comment: Actually I think for other components we can use IOC like Zenject to decrease dependencies, so I think they will be loosely coupled by this approach.
I will check that engine. Thanks

Comment: Do you guys have any idea about using MVC or MVVM ?

Answer (score 0):

after @ julxzs and i were talking...

did a little checking on best practices... i found this

[link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Toolbox)

so it turns out singleton is the way to go, check out the page, lots of good info! thx @julxzs

Comment: I would suggest using the singleton pattern over this method. That way you can be sure there is only one instance and it would be easier to access.

Comment: thats what dontdestroyonload is for. specifically to ensure that there is only one copy, and its always available.

Comment: But it comes with the downside that you have to find it by its tag on awake instead of just accessing a static instance property.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure dontdestroyonload doesn't ensure there is only one instance.

Comment: no no excuse me, the dontDestroyOnLoad keeps it alive, the static keeps you from making more than one.

Comment: I'm not sure about singelton guys. Singelton is really easy to use but it has many disadvantages. Also what about 2 players in the game ?

Comment: You should include the relevant information from a link in your answer. Presently your answer as-is does not contain an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at dependency injection technique. 
I can advice to start with [Zenject](https://github.com/svermeulen/Zenject).